# How to query Coveo rest API to lookup for a value in more than single field?

Tags: coveo

I have the following records in Coveo,

```
Record 1
@firstname = "Steve"
@lastname = "Jobs"
@fullname = "Steve Jobs"

Record 2
@firstname = "Jose"
@lastname = "Steve"
@fullname = "Jose Steve"

Record 3
@firstname = "Joe"
@lastname = "Brian"
@fullname = "Joe Brain"
```

I would like to query to get both "Steve Jobs" & "Jose Steve".

Should the query be like this (@lastname = "steve" or @firstname = "steve")???

or Do I have any other option???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Coveo query syntax, the "=" operator is the "contains keyword" operator. This means you can just use your `@fullname` field like this:

```
@fullname = "steve"
```

It will give the same results as the query you suggested:

```
@lastname = "steve" OR @firstname = "steve"
```

Note that Boolean operators need to be in uppercase in the Coveo query syntax.

More information about the Coveo query syntax and operators:

- https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/user/coveo_query_syntax_reference.htm
- https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/user/search_query_examples.htm
- https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/user/search_prefix_and_operators.htm
- https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/user/advanced_field_queries.htm